# border-bottom not working when dealing with background-color overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking the Menu and it opens, the overlay background effect doesn't work for `border-bottom` under the h2 tag.

How do I tackle this issue?

How do I go about it?

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}
```

```css
h2 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="main">
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpi0Y.jpg">
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

Comment: what exactly you want ?

Comment: the `border-bottom` also go behind the background-color. Currently, the `border-bottom` under the h2 tag is on top of the overlay. This needs to get behind/underneath.

Comment: Note how the image is also above the overlay!! I need both the border-bottom and the image to be behind/under the background overlay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the `background-color` of `document.body` is not overlaying. It is just painting the background into another color. That is why the `border-color` of `h2` is not affected at all.

To do an overlay, you must create a separate element that serves as an overlay.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft = "250px";
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
    
    /* ADD THIS */
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'block';
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.getElementById("main").style.marginLeft= "0";
    //document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    
    /* ADD THIS */
    document.getElementById('overlay').style.display = 'none';
}
```

```css
h2 {
 border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#main {
    transition: margin-left .5s;
    padding: 16px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* ADD THIS */
#overlay {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}


@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>  
</div>

<div id="main">

  <!-- ADD THIS -->
  <div id="overlay"></div> 
  
  <h2>Sidenav Push Example</h2>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpi0Y.jpg">
  <p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu, and push this content to the right. Notice that we add a black see-through background-color to body when the sidenav is opened.</p>
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
</div>
```

You can adjust the `width` and `height` of the overlay yourself.

Comment: Thank you. No matter what I do, the height of the overlay doesn't work on scroll! What am I missing?